# How to pass headers while making connection with SSE using EventSource library

Tags: java, spring-boot, header, server-sent-events

I am trying to automate Server-Sent-Event(SSE) using Java and the below code reference:

- https://github.com/BeTheCodeWithYou/Spring-Boot-SSE
- https://github.com/BeTheCodeWithYou/Spring-Boot-SSE/wiki
- https://medium.com/@bethecodewithyou/server-sent-events-development-test-automation-9ec74e2f71a

I am stuck at passing headers before making a connection to stream using the EvenSource library.

```
public Map<String, String> subscribeClient(String uuid) throws InterruptedException {
    Headers.Builder headerBuilder = new Headers.Builder();
    String dummyHeader1 = "header1:value1";
    String dummyHeade2 = "header2:value2";
    headerBuilder.add(dummyHeader1);
    headerBuilder.add(dummyHeade2);

    Headers myHeader = new Headers(headerBuilder);

    EventHandler eventHandler = new ClientEventHandler();
    String url = String.format("https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange");
    EventSource.Builder builder = new EventSource.Builder(eventHandler, URI.create(url)).headers(myHeader);
    System.out.println("client establishing connection");
    try (EventSource eventSource = builder.build()) {
        eventSource.setReconnectionTimeMs(3000);
        eventSource.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }

    System.out.println("execution success");
    return new HashMap() {{
        put("status", "success");
    }};
}
```

Throwing below error at this line: `Headers myHeader = new Headers(headerBuilder);`

```
'Headers(okhttp3.Headers.Builder)' is not public in 'okhttp3.Headers'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

Note: For reference, I've passed the dummy headers.

Comment: Problem source : 'Headers(java.lang.String[])' has private access in 'okhttp3.Headers'. Solution : .headers (headerBuilder.build());

Comment: Hi @kalpesh,
May be its too late, but still it can be helpful, try below format to add the headers:-


  `Headers httpHeaders =
        Headers.of("key","value","key1","value1"...... so on);

    EventSource.Builder builder =
        new EventSource.Builder(eventHandler, URI.create(url))
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(200))
           // .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
            .headers(httpHeaders);`